# xpath for price with currency

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<category>
    <Movi Name="Test">
        <Price>$3.95</Price>
    </Movi>
    <Movi Name="test d">
        <Price>$13.95</Price>
    </Movi>
</category>
```

can anyone help on this XML to find movie greater than $11 with XPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given all prices are in the same currency and format, this bit of XPath does the job:

```
/category/Movi[number(substring(./Price/text(), 2)) > 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, another option is:

```
//Price[number(translate(text(), '$','')) > 11]
```

Comment: The price selection mechanism is good, but the expression as a whole selects a price, not a movie (as requested in the question).